# Не работает posthtml-include

Tags: javascript

Локально работает при push на git либо ошибка 404 либо белый экран тоесть считать информацию с include не может

вот мой пробный git
https://github.com/Andrey000001/realestateS

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: В корневом каталоге должен быть `index.html`. Браузер начинает чтение именно оттуда.

Comment: Здравствуйте. я знаю пробовал ,но не работает ,локально работает ,так нет. + есть доп настойка к include там указывается что считывать ./src если у вас получится сделать в src index.html и в папке components допустим header.html и заработает на git ,я хочу понять как вы это сделали и что у меня не так